# iOS7 why won't the time show up in texts

Tags: messages, ios

I downloaded iOS7 and noticed that the time doesn't show up in texts like the older version.  How can I get the time to show up in my text messages when someone texts me? For example, when I receive a text from someone I want the time to show up in the actual conversation

Answer (score 5):

Swipe right to left to reveal the timestamps.

[image]